# 1st Time Using Case Statement Getting Errors

Tags: vba, excel-2007, case, nested-if

Below is the code I am trying to use on a Multipage Userform command button. This button should first check that you have selected one of 7 Option Buttons. If you have not it should ask you to "Select Site". If you did then based on the option you selected it should generate default values for a large group of named text boxes. However when the code runs I get an error that states "Statements or labels invalid between Select Case and first Case". I am new to using Case statements in VBA but I thought it might work better than nested ifs. However it appears I did something wrong and was hoping you guys could help me figure out what.

I am using Excel 2013 however the file will be ran on a machine using Excel 2007.

```
Private Sub SiteNext_Click()
If Me.OptionButton1.Value = False And Me.OptionButton2.Value = False And Me.OptionButton3.Value = False And Me.OptionButton4.Value = False And _
    Me.OptionButton5.Value = False And Me.OptionButton6.Value = False And Me.OptionButton7.Value = False Then
    MsgBox "Select Site"
    Exit Sub
Else

    Select Case Me.OptionButton1.Value = True

    LocalTier1.Value = "600"
    LocalTier2.Value = "250"
    LocalTier3.Value = "175"
    LocalTier4.Value = "125"
    LocalTier5.Value = "85"
    LocalTier6.Value = "65"
    LocalTier7.Value = "40"
    LocalTier8.Value = "25"
    LocalTier9.Value = "10"
    LocalTier10.Value = "5"
    LocalTier11.Value = "5"
    DriveTier1.Value = "600"
    DriveTier2.Value = "250"
    DriveTier3.Value = "175"
    DriveTier4.Value = "125"
    DriveTier5.Value = "85"
    DriveTier6.Value = "65"
    DriveTier7.Value = "40"
    DriveTier8.Value = "25"
    DriveTier9.Value = "10"
    DriveTier10.Value = "5"
    DriveTier11.Value = "5"
    OuterTier1.Value = "600"
    OuterTier2.Value = "250"
    OuterTier3.Value = "200"
    OuterTier4.Value = "150"
    OuterTier5.Value = "100"
    OuterTier6.Value = "75"
    OuterTier7.Value = "45"
    OuterTier8.Value = "30"
    OuterTier9.Value = "15"
    OuterTier10.Value = "10"
    OuterTier11.Value = "5"

    Case Me.OptionButton2.Value = True

    LocalTier1.Value = "250"
    LocalTier2.Value = "225"
    LocalTier3.Value = "150"
    LocalTier4.Value = "120"
    LocalTier5.Value = "80"
    LocalTier6.Value = "50"
    LocalTier7.Value = "25"
    LocalTier8.Value = "15"
    LocalTier9.Value = "10"
    LocalTier10.Value = "5"
    LocalTier11.Value = "5"
    DriveTier1.Value = "300"
    DriveTier2.Value = "225"
    DriveTier3.Value = "150"
    DriveTier4.Value = "120"
    DriveTier5.Value = "80"
    DriveTier6.Value = "50"
    DriveTier7.Value = "25"
    DriveTier8.Value = "15"
    DriveTier9.Value = "10"
    DriveTier10.Value = "5"
    DriveTier11.Value = "5"

    Case Me.OptionButton3.Value = True

    LocalTier1.Value = "200"
    LocalTier2.Value = "175"
    LocalTier3.Value = "125"
    LocalTier4.Value = "75"
    LocalTier5.Value = "60"
    LocalTier6.Value = "40"
    LocalTier7.Value = "20"
    LocalTier8.Value = "15"
    LocalTier9.Value = "10"
    LocalTier10.Value = "5"
    LocalTier11.Value = "5"
    DriveTier1.Value = "225"
    DriveTier2.Value = "200"
    DriveTier3.Value = "150"
    DriveTier4.Value = "100"
    DriveTier5.Value = "80"
    DriveTier6.Value = "60"
    DriveTier7.Value = "30"
    DriveTier8.Value = "20"
    DriveTier9.Value = "15"
    DriveTier10.Value = "10"
    DriveTier11.Value = "10"

    Case Me.OptionButton4.Value = True

    LocalTier1.Value = "175"
    LocalTier2.Value = "150"
    LocalTier3.Value = "100"
    LocalTier4.Value = "60"
    LocalTier5.Value = "45"
    LocalTier6.Value = "25"
    LocalTier7.Value = "10"
    LocalTier8.Value = "5"
    LocalTier9.Value = "5"
    DriveTier1.Value = "200"
    DriveTier2.Value = "175"
    DriveTier3.Value = "125"
    DriveTier4.Value = "100"
    DriveTier5.Value = "50"
    DriveTier6.Value = "30"
    DriveTier7.Value = "15"
    DriveTier8.Value = "10"
    DriveTier9.Value = "10"

    Case Me.OptionButton5.Value = True

    LocalTier1.Value = "175"
    LocalTier2.Value = "150"
    LocalTier3.Value = "100"
    LocalTier4.Value = "60"
    LocalTier5.Value = "40"
    LocalTier6.Value = "20"
    LocalTier7.Value = "15"
    LocalTier8.Value = "10"
    LocalTier9.Value = "5"
    LocalTier10.Value = "5"
    DriveTier1.Value = "175"
    DriveTier2.Value = "150"
    DriveTier3.Value = "100"
    DriveTier4.Value = "60"
    DriveTier5.Value = "40"
    DriveTier6.Value = "20"
    DriveTier7.Value = "15"
    DriveTier8.Value = "10"
    DriveTier9.Value = "5"
    DriveTier10.Value = "5"

    Case Me.OptionButton6.Value = True

    LocalTier1.Value = "75"
    LocalTier2.Value = "50"
    LocalTier3.Value = "30"
    LocalTier4.Value = "20"
    LocalTier5.Value = "15"
    LocalTier6.Value = "10"
    LocalTier7.Value = "5"
    DriveTier1.Value = "75"
    DriveTier2.Value = "50"
    DriveTier3.Value = "30"
    DriveTier4.Value = "20"
    DriveTier5.Value = "15"
    DriveTier6.Value = "10"
    DriveTier7.Value = "5"

    Case Me.OptionButton7.Value = True

    LocalTier1.Value = "50"
    LocalTier2.Value = "25"
    LocalTier3.Value = "20"
    LocalTier4.Value = "10"
    LocalTier5.Value = "5"
    LocalTier6.Value = "5"
    DriveTier1.Value = "50"
    DriveTier2.Value = "25"
    DriveTier3.Value = "20"
    DriveTier4.Value = "10"
    DriveTier5.Value = "5"
    DriveTier6.Value = "5"

    End Select

    Me.MultiPage1.Value = 1
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the generic `Select Case True`. It will evaluate each Case and do the actions in the first true one:

```
Select Case True
    Case Me.OptionButton1.Value = True
    ' actions ...
    Case Me.OptionButton2.Value = True
    ' actions ...
End Select
```

Comment: That makes so much sense. So is there a benefit of this over Nested If then because they feel the same as far as writing the code goes.

Comment: I agree. I don't see a benefit in this case.